Scroll Indicator in my wordpress site not working?
I am designing a site and I want to create a Scroll Indicator for my blog pages. In fact, I did something like this several months ago, but no matter what I did, I did not get results, so in fact, I abandoned the Scroll Indicator section and started designing other I looked at the parts and components until I came back to it another day and solved the problem, but today when I came back it still didn't work!
I use this code:
<div class="progress-container">
    <div class="progress-bar" id="Scroll_Indicator_blog"></div>
</div>

// scroll bar script
window.onscroll = function () {
    Scroll_Indicator_blog_function()
};

function Scroll_Indicator_blog_function() {
    var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
    document.getElementById("Scroll_Indicator_blog").style.width = scrolled + "%";
}

.progress-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;

    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8px;
    background: var(--vesal-background-color7);
    z-index: 9999;
}
.progress-bar {
    height: 100%;
    background: var(--vesal-background-color2);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 var(--vesal-boxshadow-color-1);
    width: 0%;
    transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}


I have tried almost everything that I can think of. In fact, if you inspect my site, you will find that by changing width: 0% and increasing it to another percentage, the mentioned golden line that indicates the volume read from your page to It is displayed correctly, so I am almost sure that the problem is in the js section, or is there a need for a special library to perform this process? Of course, I must say that I used w3s in the overall design of this section, which I will post the link below. Thank you for guiding me
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_indicator.asp

with the help of one of my friends here who guided me, I modified the js code like this:
window.onscroll = function () {
    Scroll_Indicator_blog_function()
};

function Scroll_Indicator_blog_function() {
    var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
    var height = document.body.scrollHeight - document.body.clientHeight;
    var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
    document.getElementById("Scroll_Indicator_blog").style.width = scrolled + "%";
}

.progress-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;

    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8px;
    background: var(--vesal-background-color7);
    z-index: 9999;
}
.progress-bar {
    height: 100%;
    background: var(--vesal-background-color2);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 var(--vesal-boxshadow-color-1);
    width: 0%;
    transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

<div class="progress-container">
    <div class="progress-bar" id="Scroll_Indicator_blog"></div>
</div>

But now I came to a new problem!
In the height calculated by this script, the height continues from the highest point of the Mojo account to the bottom of the page, that is, from the top of the header to the bottom of the footer, which is naturally not interesting to show how much of the content has been read by the reader!
How can I make it so that the height is only limited to the section in question, that is, for example, it counts the height of the page from the beginning of a section to its end, and does not count the comments section, header and footer?
Thanks again for the advice

Answers should not contain any questions - As a question on StackOverflow should focus on one problem at the time, I'd suggest you create a new question

If you just want basically the same behavior - the progress bar will be a 0%, when the top of the section aligns with the top of the viewport, and at 100% when the bottom of the section aligns with the bottom of the viewport, then you need to use the section's height as height value, and subtract the offset of the top edge of the section from the document's top (research, how to determine that), from the current scrollHeight. [...]

[...] If that value is <= 0, return 0 as the percentage right away, otherwise do your scrolled calculation. It might need another condition for when the percentage would go over 100% as well - or you just clamp it down, using Math.min(). That should more or less work, but since I am going over this in my head only without testing, it might need some modification or other, to work for the real use case.
